# iTunes USB sync deleted all playlists from my iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, mojave, music, playlist

I just synced my iPhone XS to my MacBook over a USB cable for the first time in a few months because I had some MP3 files I’d added to my iTunes library manually that I wanted to transfer. After the sync finished I discovered that all of my playlists had gone from the Music app on my iPhone. They’re all still there in iTunes. To add insult to injury, the MP3 files hadn’t synced either.

I have Apple Music turned off and don’t use iTunes Match. I have iTunes configured to sync my entire library rather that just selected playlists etc.

My iPhone is running iOS 13.3 and my MacBook is running macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

This stuff used to work reliably for me! Any help with getting my playlists back would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I have iTunes configured to sync my entire library rather that just selected playlists etc." — Can you dobule-check this? Screenshots would be nice to see if something is amiss.

Answer (score 1):

I synced my iPhone with iTunes again this morning and all my playlists came back! Go figure.